# enable <select> only after another <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have read at least a dozen post for enabling buttons, dropdowns, select, etc... I finally gave up. I cannot figure out the binding of the datepicker to the first dropdown and after 1st drop down for it to trigger the second to become enable.

```
<div data-role="page" id="details">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1></h1>
                    <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext">back</a>

                    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.datepicker.custom.min.js"></script>
                    <link href="../../jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                    <link href="../../jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                    <link href="../../jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function() {
                            $( "#Datepicker1" ).datepicker({
                                showOtherMonths: true,
                                regional: ['es'],
                                dayNamesMin: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab'],
                                dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy",
                            }); 
                        });


                        function enable()   {
                             document.getElementById("select2").disabled=false;
                        }

                    </script>

                    <style>
                        .datepicker{z-index:1151;}
                    </style>
            </div>



            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="controlgroup" align="center">   

                   <h2>Select Date</h2>
                    <input  type="text" required
                            placeholder="Date" 
                            data-inline="true" 
                            data-role="date"
                            id="Datepicker1"
                    input>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul> 
                        <li>
                            <select onChange="enable()" id="select1" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="a">
                                <option value="choose-one" data-placeholder="true">Quien autoriza el gasto?</option>
                                <option value="Tom">Tom</option>
                                <option value="Chris">Chris</option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <select disabled="disabled" required id="select2" data-native-menu="false" data-theme="a">
                                <option value="choose-one" data-placeholder="true">type</option>
                                <option value="car">car</option>
                                <option value="bike">bike</option>
                            </select>
                       </li>
                    </ul>  
                </div>
```

I did not post my attempt to bind the datepicker to the first drop down menu. It does not work and is excessive/very long. Hoping for someone better at handling the Select functionality of the api.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to place the JavaScript code into the `<head>` or under the `<select>` boxes?

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I actually have the JavaScript on a separate .JS file that it's included on the parent <head> tag for the HTML. I think(?) that should make it part of the DOM for the entire page.

Comment: I will try ur suggestion.   ... I do include jquery mobile in my parent tags... Could this be a problem?

Comment: jQuery Mobile shouldn't be a problem. I suggest to load all JavaScript files in the `<head>` section or before the closing `<body>` tag. For troubleshooting you can successively add your JS code.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that today. It is just weird because I do not get any errors in the console (firebug)